# Hibernate HQL Issue with IN Clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

When i try to convert following HQL query :

`select distinct rgp.dgRegexGroups.regexGroup, 0  FROM DgRegexPatterns rgp where rgp.dgRegexGroups.id not in ( 1,05,6,07)`

using Hibernate dynamic query translator, it gives me correct SQL like:

```
select
  distinct dgregexgro1_.regex_group as col_0_0_,
  0 as col_1_0_ 
 from
  dg_regex_patterns dgregexpat0_,
  dg_regex_groups dgregexgro1_ 
 where
  dgregexpat0_.regex_group_id=dgregexgro1_.id 
  and (
   dgregexpat0_.regex_group_id not in  ( 1,5,6,7 )
  )
```

But if I add 08 or 09 in the IN clause it gives me QuerySyntaxException.

```
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 9 near line 1, column 136 [select distinct rgp.dgRegexGroups.regexGroup, 0  FROM 
com.dataguise.hibernate.DgRegexPatterns rgp where rgp.dgRegexGroups.id not in ( 09)]
```

Did anyone know why this is happening? Is it a hibernate version specific issue? As i am currently using Hibernate-3.3 version. Did someone test this issue in the latest hibernate version?

Comment: Have you tried 8 and 9? 08 and 09 might be interpreted as (illegal) Octal numbers.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic query from the translator ? Can't you use HQL query directly ? How does your query look like after adding 08 & 09 ?

Comment: Hi mkm13, yes i tried with 8 and 9 and it is working fine with them but will you please about elaborate why it considers 08 and 09 as illegal octal numbers because again query run successfully for 010...........017 numbers.

Comment: I agree with mkm13 that it might consider 08 and 09 an invalid octal numbers hence query is breaking. :)

Answer (score 0):

Will you try to replace hard coded parameters in "in" section with query parameter, like ":p". And then path your parameters as List and call query execution.

Comment: If you want to suggest or ask the OP to try something, pls do so in the comments not as an answer :)